# How do I get the difference between two date variables in SSRS

Tags: sql, date, datetime, reporting-services

If I use this query it work because the dates are the same:

```
    DECLARE @Start datetime
    DECLARE @End datetime
    DECLARE @ServerName varchar(128)
    SET @Start = '2014-01-24'
    SET @End = '2014-01-24'
    SET @ServerName = 'ServerName'

    SELECT ServerName, cntr_value, collection_datetime
     FROM PLE
     WHERE CONVERT(DATE, collection_datetime) = @Start 
     AND CONVERT(DATE, collection_datetime) = @End 
     AND ServerName = @ServerName
```

However, I want to use the @Start and @End as SSRS parameters therefore I need to view data from a specified date range so I would think I would use something like below...except it doesn't work.

```
     DECLARE @Start datetime
     DECLARE @End datetime
     DECLARE @ServerName varchar(128)
     SET @Start = '2014-01-24'
     SET @End = '2014-01-27'
     SET @ServerName = 'Server'


    SELECT ServerName, cntr_value, collection_datetime
     FROM PLE
     WHERE CONVERT(DATE, collection_datetime) = @Start 
     BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, collection_datetime) = @End 
     AND ServerName = @ServerName
```

Obviously I can't use BETWEEN, but what else can I use to make this work?

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, collection_datetime) BETWEEN @Start AND @End ` ?

Comment: @StuartLC The problem with this approach is that it invalidates possible usage of index(es) that OP may have defined on `collection_datetime` effectively causing full scan each time

Answer (score 1):

Do it in an **index-friendly** way

```
SELECT ServerName, cntr_value, collection_datetime
  FROM PLE
 WHERE collection_datetime >= @Start 
   AND collection_datetime <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @End)
   AND ServerName = @ServerName
```

**Note:** When you apply a function to a column in `WHERE` clause you prevent the Database Engine from using any index (indices) you may have (and you better do) on this column effectively causing a full scan.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d9be/1)** demo

Recommended reading:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by @AaronBertrand